# Converting int to byte in java

Tags: java

I have an int variable in java whose value is less than 256. So Can I store it in a Single byte variable.

I performed the following code.

```
   int i =247;
   byte b = (byte) i ;
```

But When I print it,

```
   System.out.println(" i = "+(int)b);
```

It outputs
       i = -9

Is it possible to convert int values less than 256 to single byte variables.
Pls. Help..

Answer (score 4):

This isn't going to work. The `MAX_VALUE` for `byte` is 127 because bytes are signed in Java. (Consequently, the `MIN_VALUE` is -128. This is your typical [Two's Compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) pattern.)

That being said, you have a couple options:

1. Leave it as an int and just use an int for your calculations. This might even be faster for you.
2. Leave it as a byte even if the number isn't correct. The numbers might not be correct in Java, but if all you care about is the bits being correct, they will be correct. So you can send that bite (which is a -9 in Java) across a webservice to another app that reads it as an unsigned byte, and it will read it as `247` correctly.